# Deploying site using Git (Dreamhost) not working

Tags: git, deployment, dreamhost

I followed the instructions in this [guide](http://blog.brandonevans.ca/post/19685508893/deploying-websites-with-git-on-dreamhost) to the letter in order to deploy a project to a remote repo using Git. There are no errors when I do this but nothing on the remote site changes. I see this when pushing via this:

```
git push dreamhost master

Counting objects: 252, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (250/250), done.
Writing objects: 100% (252/252), 994.11 KiB, done.
Total 252 (delta 100), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://[username]@bartow.dreamhost.com/home/[username]/[filename].git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

I have a post-receive hook setup as well that should run:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/home/timjaeger/[sitename] --git-dir=/home/timjaeger/[sitename].git
checkout -f
```

Since I am not getting any error messages it is difficult to know how to troubleshoot this - where do I begin? I am a beginner at using Git for deployment.

Comment: Is `checkout -f` on the same line than `git --work-tree...`?

Comment: yes it is on the same line. I also ran chmod +x on the hooks/post-receive file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the post-receive to this:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/timjaeger/[sitename].com git checkout -f
```

worked. [This article](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) helped in finding the solution.

Comment: Don't forget to make sure you set the post-receive file's permissions via `chmod +x post-receive`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a working tree at `/home/timjaeger/[sitename]`, then your git repo cannot be `/home/timjaeger/[sitename].git`.

It should be `/home/timjaeger/[sitename]/.git`, but that would make `/home/timjaeger/[sitename]` a non-bare repo to which it would be unwise to push directly.

The work tree shoudl be separate from the bare repo git directory `/home/timjaeger/[sitename].git`.

By *not* mentioning the git-dir option (which the [OP squeezemylime](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350119/squeezemylime) [recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15721717/6309)), you keep the hook current execution directory in place (i.e. that hook will look the git repository there), while specifying a different working tree.